# Re-apply table formulas on org-mode export

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I'm using an org-mode file to do some filesystem monitoring. To that purpose I have a table in which I'm calling code blocks through org-sbe in the formulas. It looks like this:

```
#+NAME: part-size
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var mach="" :var part="" :var bs="TB" :exports none :results silent
 tmp=($(df -B ${bs} /net/${mach}/${part} | tail -1 ))
 bc -l <<< "scale=2; ${tmp[1]}/1024/1024"
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: part-used
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var mach="" :var part="" :var bs="TB" :exports none :results silent
 tmp=($(df -B${bs} /net/${mach}/${part} | tail -1))
 bc -l <<< "scale=2; ${tmp[2]}/1024/1024"
#+END_SRC

| machine | partition | size[TB] | used[TB] | available[TB] |
|---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------|
| mach1   | part1     |     60.0 |     56.0 |           4.0 |
| mach1   | part2     |     15.0 |     12.5 |           2.5 |
| mach2   | part1     |     40.5 |     10.5 |          30.0 |
|---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------------|
| total   |           |    115.5 |     79.0 |          36.5 |
#+TBLFM: @>$3..@>$5=vsum(@I..II)::@2$3..@9$3='(org-sbe part-size (mach $$1) (part $$2) (bs \"1MB\"))::@2$4..@9$4='(org-sbe part-used (mach $$1) (part $$2) (bs \"1MB\"))::@2$5..@9$5=$-2 - $-1
```

My problem is that I export that file regularly and automatically to a web page but the content of the table doesn't get updated. So I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically re-apply the table formulas on export in the same way that you can run code blocks on export.

Comment: You might get a quicker answer on the [emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) specific site. I suspect you'll want to modify one of the `org` export hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's [there](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40951/re-apply-table-formulas-on-org-mode-export)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified example that gets an updated time in the table every time you export, using the mechanism that Seth Rothschild suggested in the comment:

```
* code                                                     :noexport:                                                                                           

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(defun tables-recalc (backend)
    (org-table-recalculate-buffer-tables))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'tables-recalc)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| tables-recalc |

* table
#+NAME: gettime
#+begin_src shell 
date
#+end_src
| time                         |
|------------------------------|
| Wed Apr 11 16:27:09 EDT 2018 |
#+TBLFM: $> = '(org-sbe gettime)
```